# Single selection grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

Hello I am trying to add selection logic to my material ui grid(table).

This is what I return,

```
return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <Table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <CatalogRightGridHeader selected={selected} />
        <TableBody xs={12} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          {value.map((row) => {
            return (
              <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.nodeId}>
                <TableCell style={{ width: "10px!important", padding: 2 }}>
                  <Checkbox/>
                </TableCell>
                {row.rowItems
                  .sort(
                    (row1, row2) => row1.column.sequence - row2.column.sequence
                  )
                  .map((column) => {
                    return column.column.dataType === "DATE" ? (
                      <TableCell
                        key={column.id}
                        align={column.align}
                      >
                        {format(
                          new Date(parseInt(column.value)),
                          dateFormat(),
                          new Date()
                        )}
                      </TableCell>
                    ) : (
                      <TableCell
                        key={column.id}
                        align={column.align}
                      >
                        {column.value}
                      </TableCell>
                    );
                  })}
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
```

I want to have a logic on checkbox so whenever I check them I want to get checked row data and it should uncheck whenever I check another checkbox. I would appreciate if u could give me some tips how to do it or help me doing it.

Comment: Please provide a sample image of what you want to achieve.

Comment: https://ibb.co/H4S4g9K here's image, so what I am trying to do is to have single selection . Point is when I check box it has no handler yet, I want to add handler that's gonna have single selection, and get the `row` from map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at MUI's `DataGrid` which comes with the checkbox selections.

Also, it sounds like you want these to act like radio buttons, which, the UX difference is that checkboxes are like multiple selects, whereas radio buttons infer that only one can be selected.

If you want to stay with a vanilla table, then adding in the checkbox like that is fine, from there, when you map, add in an index. The checkboxes need to be controlled

```
 const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(null)

const handleCheckChange = (event, index) => {
  // If checkbox is changed to checked, set the index
  if (event.target.checked) {
    setChecked(index)
  } 
  // Since on change is fired every time the state changes, it'll fire when it
  // gets unchecked by checking something else, so only set back to null when 
  // it's unchecked while being the actively checked row
  else if (!event.target.checked && index === checked) {
    setChecked(null)
  }
}


value.map((row, index) => {
  return (
    <TableRow hover role='checkbox' tabIndex={-1} key={row.nodeId}>
      <TableCell style={{ width; '10px!important', padding: 2 }}>
        <Checkbox
          checked={checked === index}
          onChange={(event) => handleCheckChange(event, index)}
        />
      </TableCell>
      ...
  ) 
}
```

From here, you now know the row that is checked and can pull that data as

```
rowData[checked]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer I have already solved it `const [checkIndex, setCheckIndex] = useState(-1); ` by adding this state then I used 

`  const changeHandler = (e, row, index) => {
    setEditItem(row);
    setSelectedItem(false);
    setCheckIndex(index);
  }; `

my onchange event to pass the index  then I added this logic to the checkbox's prop 

`checked={checkIndex === -1 ? false : index === checkIndex}` it solved my problem but I am sure ur answer would solved it too. thanks again